# 16.04 Monitor goes to sleep after 1 minute of use, gtx 770

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I'm in quiet a spot of bother; after booting on 16.04 and 30s-1min of use, my display seems to shut down on both my GPU (gtx 770) and motherboard video output. During these 30s everything works just fine. I'm then forced to hard reset the PC, and if I want to have a chance at doing anything i have to remove my GPU and plug in the motherbord VGA.

It seems to be linked with the nvidia drivers, as the nouveau drivers don't give me this problem (but my performances are horrible with nouveau)

Up until now I've tried :

- adding nomodeset to my kernel boot,
- adding nouveau.blacklist=1 to my kernel boot,
- trying every driver in the additional drivers list (340, 410, 390 and what not),
- hitting my head very hard on a wall while shouting like a dying animal.

None seems to work, and I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. Any suggestions ?

My config :

gtx 770, i5-3470, MSI B75A-G43 Gaming.

Thanks.

Comment: And i meant to say Hi, also.